# How To Pass MoPub Native Ad To Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, mopub

## Question

I'm researching how to integrate MoPub's Android and iOS native ads implementation over to Flutter. **What data from the native ad received from MoPub in the *onNativeLoad* method below would need to be passed in order for Flutter to display properly?**

## Potential Solution

Based on MoPub's [documentation for manual native ads integration](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/native/#method-3-manual-integration) (on Android) the ad data can be received and passed via an [**EventChannel**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html) in order to display in Flutter's UI. I'm not sure which information from the `NativeAd` object would need to be passed to Flutter.

```
 moPubNativeNetworkListener = new MoPubNative.MoPubNativeNetworkListener() {
     @Override
     public void onNativeLoad(final NativeAd nativeAd) {
         Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad has loaded.");
     }
     @Override
     public void onNativeFail(NativeErrorCode errorCode) {
         Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad failed to load with error: " + errorCode.toString());
     }
 };
```

Developer's usage of MoPub on Flutter would key as it allows access to the major ad networks and thus provides effective monetization.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I've considering just building a mopub plugin, also partly cause of the lack of ad network plugins other than admob

Comment: I have stayed with Kotlin development so far @Amin.